# How to Ignore a Missing Field in Solr Request Parameters API?

Tags: solr

I have an old solr instance that has enabled a customer parameter in the json API, e.g.

`?json.customParam="eeebc"`

In order to upgrade Solr to a new version (on a new machine), I simply want to ignore it instead of solr returning an exception so some level of backward compatibility is possible. The current exception is:

`Unknown top-level key in JSON request: customParam`

I'm hoping there is some fairly simple way to just ignore that parameter using the schema/solrconfig etc.